# <ui:repeat> appears in resulting HTML

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, uirepeat

I am having a simple backing bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class BackingBean {

  public String[] getStorageLocations() {
    return new String[]{"0088", "0016", "0022"};
  }
}
```

In the xhtml file I am using a `<ui:repeat />` tag to output the array of strings from the backing bean:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.storageLocations}" var="location">
  <h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <h:outputText value="#{location}" />
  </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

What I am expecting is this:

```
<div>0088</div>
<div>0016</div>
<div>0022</div>
```

What I acutally receive from JSF is this:

```
<ui:repeat>0088</ui:repeat>
<ui:repeat>0016</ui:repeat>
<ui:repeat>0022</ui:repeat>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using GF4. This was a bug. Try updating your javax.faces jar with the latest released one.

Comment: Thank you, the `<ui:repeat />` tags are now gone in the html output. But the `<divs />` are still not produced. Is this related to the bug in javax.faces.jar?

Comment: Welcome. I haven't experienced this issue before. To check if this is a bug, try adding a styleClass to the panelgroup. If it doesn't work, I would raise a new question. good luck

Comment: Adding a styleClass worked and produced the div correctly. Thanks again, john d, you saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution: change the xmlns url to sun's:

from:

```
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
```

to:

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```

(thanks http://blog.coffeebeans.at/?p=775)